# Consume same WCF Service from multiple projects in solution

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy-classes, endpoints, multiple-projects

**Situation:**

I have a solution of multiple projects:

- Executable App #1
- Executable App #2
- WCF Project
- *Shared* Project
- *"Other"* Project
- ...

Now I need to consume the WCF service in my executable app #1.
E.g. to retrieve information about a user from a `UserService` in the WCF project.
Due to both executables require a login, handled by the `UserService`, I added a ´Authenticate´ method in my *Shared Project*. This authentication is also handled by the `UserService`.

**Problem:**

Now I have to add a service reference inside each project, which is actually not a problem. **But** now I get generated the proxy classe and the endpoint in all three projects.

I see this as an issue, due to I have to update all 3 service references:

- Executable App #1 requires only the endpoint (proxy class of shared project could be used)
- Executable App #2 requires only the endpoint (same as above)
- *Shared* Project requires only the proxy class

**Question:**

Is there any nice solution to add a service reference without creating the endpoint configuration in the shared project and without creating the proxy classes in the executable apps?

Comment: is your WCF are SOAP? if it is then you are on right path. but if your services are RESTFul then why don't you use **WebRequest** ?

Comment: @MuneebAmjad The services are SOAP.

Comment: Why not place all of your service references into a class library project, then reference that project? You could even make the proxy classes `internal`, and expose only the interface you like through  facade classes.

Comment: @JohnSaunders This *IS* what I'm doing right now. But the executable projects require - predefined by Microsoft - the endpoint configurations. And those come along with adding the service references. I could add them manually, but this would be, indeed, a pain in the a**...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that this is your issue. That's how _all_ configuration works in .NET, not just WCF configuration. It doesn't look like `<system.serviceModel>` supports the `configSource` attribute.

Comment: @JohnSaunders *sigh* ... so adding and updating the service references in "all" projects is the only solution? Well, thank you anyway.

Comment: No. Add and update in the shared class library. Copy the configuration from the app.config of the shared library to the config files of your .exe projects. Update as required.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I implemented something similar to this recently, and this is what I did. I think it provides nice separation of concerns and keeps you from having to generate a proxy class in all your executables.

- Create a ServiceContract project. This will contain the interface that defines the contract for your WCF service.
- Create a ClientProxy project, and include a ClientProxy class. This
  project will reference your ServiceContact, and will set up the
  bindings for your WCF service. I recommend that you pass the URI of
  your WCF service into this class in the constructor.

The proxy class should look something like this:

```
public class ClientProxy 
{
    public IMyWCFService service;

    public ClientProxy(string uri)
    {
        // Any channel setup code goes here
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
        binding.MaxBufferSize = //whatever
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = //whatever
        ...

        ChannelFactory<IMyWCFService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyWCFService>(binding, address);
        service = factory.CreateChannel();
    }
}
```

Now, your WCF service project will contain a reference to the ServiceContract, and you will implement the interface here.

Your executables will contain references to the ServiceContract and ClientProxy projects.

I hope this helps you. Let me know if you need clarification on anything.